# Stop jQuery timer at 0 using clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm having issues using clearInterval to stop my simple count timer once it is equal to 0. Essentially, timer goes past 0 into negative values instead of stopping at 0. I am creating a basic quiz that ideally will alert the user of the correct answers once the timer reaches and stops at 0.

Below is current code:

```js
var count = 10;
var gameTime;

gameTime = setInterval("counter()", 1000);

function convertSeconds(s){
    var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return min + ":" + sec;
}

function counter(){
count--;
$("#timer").text(convertSeconds(count));
}

if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval("#timer");
} else {
    //Do nothing
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Trivia</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div id ="timer">10</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well one your if statement is outside your function, it can't be used if it isn't inside it. Also you need to look at the documentation of [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) for what to pass to it

Comment: I initially passed gameTime through it since I had it equal to the setInterval function, but changed it to timer as I was unaware of the error in my if statement placement. Thanks. I asked rjustin below, but would this be an example of a scope issue or is it just a syntax error (if statement not passing through function since it's not inside the function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your if check into the counter function and clear the gameTime variable.

setInterval runs the provided function at the given interval so anything you want to run or check on that interval must happen in the provided function.

```js
var count = 10;
var gameTime;

gameTime = setInterval("counter()", 1000);

function convertSeconds(s){
    var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return min + ":" + sec;
}

function counter(){
count--;
$("#timer").text(convertSeconds(count));
if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(gameTime);
} else {
    //Do nothing
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Trivia</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div id ="timer">10</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow. So was the issue basically with scope / order of the statements being called? I spent a few hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working and even tried writing a separate stop function containing clearInterval.

Comment: @chlc Basically the counter function is what gets run every second. If your check for 0 is not checked every second then you wont see it stop because it wasnt ever checked. 

Also to clear an interval you must use the variable you set it to originally.